# FFMPEG static build with RTMP support?

Tags: linux, build, ffmpeg, protocols

Is there any FFMPEG static build(linux CentOS in my case) download link with an RTMP support(`--enable-librtmp`)? 
I have try to build one but it's unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

The [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page has links to several static builds:

- [FFmpeg Static Builds by Burek](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/)
- [FFmpeg Static Builds by Relaxed](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/index.html)

Burek's supports 32bit and 64bit with kernel 3.2.x+. Relaxed's supports 64bit with kernel 2.6.26. Burek provides more frequent updates.

From an older build by Burek:

```
$ ./ffmpeg -protocols
...
Supported file protocols:
Input:
applehttp
cache
concat
crypto
data
ffrtmphttp
file
gopher
hls
http
httpproxy
mmsh
mmst
pipe
rtmp
rtmpt
rtp
srtp
tcp
udp

Output:
ffrtmphttp
file
gopher
http
httpproxy
md5
pipe
rtmp
rtmpt
rtp
srtp
tcp
udp
```

Comment: Still it raise an error message `Server error:
rtmp://xx.xx.xxx.xx/oflaDemo/livestream: Operation not permitted
`. The latest version of Burek's static build doesn't include `--enable-librtmp`

Comment: You didn't mention an error message in your original question. FFmpeg has native RTMP support, so `--enable-librtmp` is generally not a requirement.